# How to add logical OR constraint in OR-Tools?

Tags: integer-programming, scheduling, or-tools

Let's say nurses normally do 1 shift

```
for d in all_days:
    for s in all_shifts:
        model.Add(sum(shifts[(n, d, s)] for n in all_nurses) == 1)
```

But I want to make nurses either do 1 shift or 3 shifts (but no 2 shifts). How do I combine between

```
        model.Add(sum(shifts[(n, d, s)] for n in all_nurses) == 1)
```

and

```
        model.Add(sum(shifts[(n, d, s)] for n in all_nurses) == 3)
```

?

Comment: I think it would be better if you use or-tools-discuss https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/or-tools-discuss

Comment: I think my question may also be helpful for other similar optimization libraries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also do:

```py
model.AddLinearExpressionInDomain(sum(variables), cp_model.Domain.FromValues([1, 3]))
```

Or even:

```py
for d in all_days:
    for s in all_shifts:
        b = model.NewBoolVar("")
        model.Add(sum(shifts[(n, d, s)] for n in all_nurses) == 1).OnlyEnforceIf(b)
        model.Add(sum(shifts[(n, d, s)] for n in all_nurses) == 3).OnlyEnforceIf(b.Not())
```

PS:

> Let's say nurses normally do 1 shift

Wouldn't that be:

```py
for n in all_nurses:
    model.Add(sum(shifts[(n, d, s)] for d in all_days for s in all_shifts) == 1)
```

Comment: TIL OR-tools has a nice shortcut for that. Do you know where to learn more about those shortcuts? The python reference didn't give enough examples

Comment: I learnt by reading the python reference https://google.github.io/or-tools/python/ortools/sat/python/cp_model.html + searching for usage in the repo https://github.com/google/or-tools/search?l=Python&q=addlinearexpressionindomain

Answer (score 8):

Introduce a binary variable $x_{d,s}$ and change the right hand side to $1+2x_{d,s}$.

Comment: Good library-agnostic solution!